# Keeping track of number of logins with awk

Tags: awk

I am trying to list current users with the count of number of logins by using AWK. First part is easy, but I am stuck at the second part. How can I retrieve number of logins, if there is such a file that keeps the number of logins? If not, how can I implement such a system in awk?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not quite clear to me what you are asking for, but if you just want to show the logged in users and how many logins each user currently has, then something like the following will do it.

```
$ users | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[$i]++;} END{for (u in a) printf("%s %d\n", u, a[u])}'
```

It loops through the output of the [`users`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/users/) command, fills up an array with the count of each one, and then dumps the count in the `END` portion of the awk script.

Comment: That's what I'm asking. Thanks!